# Why is the "webpack" item not recognized as a cmdlet, function

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Although I use the command to install webpack as a global.

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli -g
```

It still prompts 'Cannot recognize the "webpack" item as a cmdlet' when using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [webpack to environment path](https://www.programmersought.com/article/91895265536/) for it to be recognized.